# Add title to each grid with ImageGrid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib's `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.ImageGrid` to generate two grids, each size (3,3):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
from graspologic.plot import binary_heatmap, adjplot

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))

grid1 = ImageGrid(fig, 121, (3, 3), axes_pad=.05, share_all=True)
grid2 = ImageGrid(fig, 122, (3, 3), axes_pad=.05, share_all=True)

plt.tight_layout(w_pad=3)
```

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to add a title to each ImageGrid, so that there would be two titles, one for the left 3x3 grid, and one for the right one.

It seems like this should be pretty straightforward, but I haven't been able to figure it out so far. Anybody familiar with this and have any good ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a built in way to set the title of an ImageGrid.

However, you could get the list of axes objects that are used to make the ImageGrid using `grid1.axes_all`, then set the title of the top middle one. It's a bit of a workaround, but works in this case.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))

grid1 = ImageGrid(fig, 121, (3, 3), axes_pad=.05, share_all=True)
grid2 = ImageGrid(fig, 122, (3, 3), axes_pad=.05, share_all=True)

plt.tight_layout(w_pad=3)

grid1.axes_all[1].set_title("Left hand title")
grid2.axes_all[1].set_title("Right hand title")
```

[image]

Comment: Ended up doing this. Kinda hacky, but it works! Thanks dude. See here for the use case :) http://docs.neurodata.io/graph-stats-book/representations/ch6/multigraph-representation-learning.html